# Authenticate Office 365 API and Send Email from ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, office365, azure-active-directory

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application that wants to send email messages to different users. The goal is to have a re-usable API in my MVC app that can send single/bulk emails from different views.

My idea is to create a custom Web API that my MVC application can call to send emails using Office 365 API. Now assume that we have 2 projects:

1. MVC Web App -> This contains a page with UI fields like To, From, Body, Send Button etc.
2. MVC Web API -> This contains references to Office 365 library and endpoints to send emails

Will this scenario work to send emails as I do not want the users to be redirected to their individual sign in page and enter their office 365 credentials. I was wondering if I could call some office 365 API endpoint and pass them an email address like xyz@office365.com and it would send me an auth token which I could use to send the emails.

Correct me if I am wrong or anyone has a better idea?

-------UPDATE ON 17th May 2017 -------

Sorry Nan Yu for replying late. I was a bit occupied with other priorities so did not get a chance to look into more details on your code samples. I appreciate your suggestions but at this point I have other priorities to work on. I don't know how will I be able to authenticate against the AD as we have a different sort of architecture. Imagine we have 5 companies who use our web application. All 5 companies have their own Office 365 accounts and AD. We use our SQL database to authenticate them before giving access to our web application like most web applications will do but we cannot authenticate them against their AD as they are not part of our AD network.

Answer (score 1):

If you want user to authentication in Azure AD in MVC app(user login with their credentials) , then in mvc app calls a web API and then the web API calls O365 rest apis after obtaining a token to act On Behalf Of the original user. You could use the OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow . For more information about how the protocols work , you could refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api) and [this code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof) .

If you want to call Office 365 library in web api  using its app identity (instead of a user's identity) to get access token  , without any human interaction such as an interactive sign-on dialog , you could try OAuth 2.0 client credentials . Please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api) and you could related code samples in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-code-samples)(Server or Daemon Application to Web API section).

**Update :**

You could 1) use asp.net identity and enable azure ad External login , then in web api you could send mail On Behalf Of the original user by using OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow .

2) Acquire token With client credentials flow in web api  :

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=<clientid>&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com/&client_secret=   
<client secret>&grant_type=client_credentials
```

Then using the access token(app identity) you could send mail by :

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userPrincipalName>/sendMail
Content-type: application/json
Authorization : Bearer token

{
  "message": {
    "subject": "Meet for lunch?",
    "body": {
      "contentType": "Text",
      "content": "The new cafeteria is open."
    },
    "toRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "ny@chencl.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
      }
    ],
  },
  "saveToSentItems": "true"
}
```

You could pass userPrincipalName from MVC . And you should grant `Send mail as any user`  application permission of `microsoft graph` for you web api in azure portal.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My MVC web app currently uses ASP.NET Identity to authenticate users against my SQL db. Will this interfere with me making any AD authentication? I really want to use Office 365 for email communication. So once a user is logged in to my MVC app, it shud allow the user to send email from xyz@off365.com to abc@off365.com without being asked for any login info. Will your soln-2 work in this case?

Comment: Nan Yu - I have added my comments to the question above. Thanks again for your suggestions

Comment: @user2272865  Does original question solved  ? Your edited question is not the same scenario as the original one , SQL database means azure sql database ? You just need to make sure sql database could be access and that is not a azure ad question , i would suggest you start a new thread ,and add related tag .